# What to include in email headers, using php mail()?

Tags: php, email, header

When I want to send email, my codes look like these:

```
$headers =  'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: me@localhost' . "\r\n";

// Email Variables
$toUser  = 'you@something';
$subject = "Testing";
$body    = '<html><head><title></title></head><body>
            This is my picture <img src="http://domain.com/me.jpg">';

if(mail($toUser,$subject,$body,$headers)){
  echo "Email sent!!";
}
```

Here are my questions:

1. Must I include the `<html>, <head>, <title>...` tags?
2. Can I use stylesheet? For example, `<div style="...">` ?
3. I tested send the email to several accounts, if I include the `<img>` tag (for include image), it goes to junk mails, but if just plain text it goes to inbox. Anyone has any idea why it is? And how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You should send your e-mail as `multipart` with a `text/plain` portion too.

That'll let people with text-only mail clients read it, and also count in your favour with any spam detection systems.

Answer (score 0):

1. No, some mail clients (especially webmail) will strip out anything before `<body>`
2. You can use inline styles `<div style="">` - using an external .css file is not recommended as it may not be loaded.
3. If you only have a bit of text and an image it looks a lot like spam.  If you had more text it may get treated differently.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with css in mail is that (again) is not standard in all mail services

here will find a complete descripction

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/